# check inside array if the value sperated by comman

Tags: php, arrays, replace

Results in array as below,

[image]

How can I convert the above array as below:

```
array:3[
   0=>"11856"
   1=>"12235"
   2=>"11843"
```

So if any value is separated by comma, remove from that index array and add another index with removed value.

I have tried logic as below:

```
foreach($domains as $row){       

    $domain = explode(',',$row);
    $row = $domain;  

    }
```

No Luck, Any better approach?

Hope make sense. Thanks in advance for all.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through your `source array` and explode it with `,` character. And after explode it return Array, just loop this array push it add to your `return array`

```
function convert_array($data) {
    $ret = array();

    foreach($data as $d) {
        $tmp = explode(',', $d);
        foreach($tmp as $t) {
            $ret[] = $t;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}

$data = array("11856,12235,113", "11843");

var_dump(convert_array($data));
```

and output is

```
array(3) {
    [0] => 11856
    [1] => 12235
    [2] => 113
    [3] => 11843
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers,
I manage to achieve the requirement just in one line of code as below.

```
 $domain = explode(",",implode(",",$domains));
```

First **Implode** by comma, Then **explode** the result. Done the magic.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution as per your question. This is very simple and easy solution. I used your code for solve your problem.

```
$domains = array(0=>"11856,12235", 1=>"11843");

foreach($domains as $row){

$domain = explode(',',$row);
foreach($domain as $d){

    $a[] = $d;

}

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => 11856
[1] => 12235
[2] => 11843
)
```